# Which of these norms are equivalent to the canonical one

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis

Regarding the space of continuously differentiable functions $C^1([0,1])$, I am wondering which of these norms are equivalent to the norm $||x||= ||x||_{\infty} + ||x'||_{\infty}$. 
The candidates are given by:
$$||x|| = \text{max}( |\int_0^1 x(t)dt|,||x'||_{\infty})$$
$$||x|| = \sqrt{(\int_0^1 x(t)^2dt + \int_0^1 x'(t)^2dt)}$$

I am just interested in counterexamples (probably a sequence that shows that they are not equivalent AND a positive answer( but without a proof, i want to show this by myself ;-))

Comment: Let me say this: One is equivalent, the other not.

Comment: Can you say which one is the equivalent one?

Comment: What's your impression, which one is it?

Comment: well, the first one looks strange; I know that the integral norm is not equivalent to the absolute maximum norm on the continuous functions. Maybe this behavior is transitive in the sense that therefore the first one is not equivalent to the given one in this space too. Actually, I have no experience with the 2nd one, which is why I can't say much about it.

Comment: actually, it is not that obvious to me, since I also see a lot of examples that claim that the $L2$ norm does not form $C[0,1]$ in a complete vector space. So I have reasoning against both norms.

Comment: okay, after thinking about it for a few more minutes, i guess the integral is the more rough tool, so probably the 2nd one is not equivalent...but I would love to know how you see this that fast or did you prove it?

Comment: thank you Daniel Fischer. i found a counterexample for the second norm.

Comment: Good. Sorry, been occupied elsewhere. Presumably something along the lines of $x_n'$ converging to $\chi_{[0,\frac12)}$ in $L^2$ that shows that the space is not complete under the second norm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the definition of $C^1$ norm, the term $\sup |x'|$ is much more important than the other one. The other one gets thrown in just to give positive norm to $\mathbf 1(x)\equiv 1$. Here is a precise statement to this effect.

**Claim**. Let $|\cdot |_*$ be a seminorm such that $\alpha:=|\mathbf 1|_*>0$ and  $|x|_*\le K\sup |x'|$ for all $x\in C^1$, with $K$ independent of $x$. Then $|x|_*+\sup |x'|$ is equivalent to the "canonical" norm $\|\|_{C^1}$.

Some other examples of suitable seminorms: $|x(0)|$, $|x(1/2)|$, $\left|\int_{1/3}^{2/3} x\right|$...

The proof of the claim is hidden at the end.

---

For a counterexample to second one, I would use $x(t)=(t+1/n)^{1/3}$ which is bounded in the second norm, but not in $C^1$.

---

> Proof. By assumption,  $|x|_*+\sup |x'|\le (K+1)\|x\|_{C^1}$. For the reverse inequality,  observe that  $$|x|_* \ge | (\sup|x|) \mathbf 1|_* - |x-\sup |x||_* \ge  \alpha \sup |x|  - K\sup|x' | $$ Hence, $$(K+1)(|x|_* +  \sup|x' |) \ge \alpha \sup |x| + \sup|x'| \ge \min(1,\alpha) \|x\|_{C^1} $$ as claimed. $\quad\Box$